# Ошибка VUE 3 при запуске in ./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, node-modules

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                               13:47:10
 error  in ./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (763:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| }
| class RefImpl {
>     _rawValue;
|     _shallow;
|     _value;

 @ ./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js 1:0-233 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 
2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 16:4-17 40:4-17 107:13-18 108:32-37 115:16-21 1958:8-13 1962:13-23 1968:35-45 1970:16-21 1973:21-31 2071:19-25 2094:8-12 2135:8-13 2210:29-34 2557:27-30 2558:26-29 2559:28-31 2905:16-29 2912:16-29 3043:28-36 3362:41-56 3378:28-33 3463:8-15 3500:32-37 3647:27-32 3823:29-34 3951:12-25 3958:12-25 4568:17-22 4592:13-18 5173:26-32 5336:8-21 5340:8-21 5755:16-20 5761:12-16 6296:27-32 6328:12-19 6338:16-23 6356:93-100 6357:15-20 6767:60-75 6768:60-75 6769:60-75 6770:59-74 6847:16-21 6997:16-21 7150:21-28 7160:8-21 7161:134-149 7162:8-21 7210:30-39 7264:8-21 7266:8-21 7314:23-38 7334:46-55 7334:56-63 7389:14-24 7576:21-26 7586:21-31 7593:24-34 7596:21-31 7624:53-58 7630:52-57 7696:48-53
 @ ./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js
 @ ./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.22:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

**webpack.config.js:**
let service = process.VUE_CLI_SERVICE

if (!service || process.env.VUE_CLI_API_MODE) {
  const Service = require('./lib/Service')
  service = new Service(process.env.VUE_CLI_CONTEXT || process.cwd())
  service.init(process.env.VUE_CLI_MODE || process.env.NODE_ENV)
}

module.exports = service.resolveWebpackConfig()

**pac..json:**
     "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "vue": "^3.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
          "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
          "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
          "parser": "babel-eslint"
        },
        "rules": {}
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Чем собираете? [мой комментарий достаточно длинный]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос конфигурацию webpack, пожалуйста

Comment: В вопрос, все уточнения добавляйте в вопрос, вы можете его править.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено!

1. Транспилируем @vue/reactivity

   ```
   // vue.config.js

   module.exports = {
     transpileDependencies: ['@vue/reactivity']
   }
   ```
2. Опустить версию до to Vue 3.1.2

   ```
   npm uninstall vuenpm i -S vue@3.1.2
   ```
3. Использовать Vue CLI 5 (beta)

   ```
   npm i -g @vue/cli@5
   ```